# Getting exception - Element move is not expected

Tags: magento2.3, exception

**Site Link :**  https://www.leis.synergixfast.com

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'move':
>   This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( action, arguments,
>   block, container, referenceBlock, uiComponent ). Line: 834
>
> Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute
>   'ifconfig' is not allowed. Line: 891
>
> Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute
>   'ifconfig' is not allowed. Line: 903
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):
>   Element 'move': This element is not expected. Expected is one of (
>   action, arguments, block, container, referenceBlock, uiComponent ).
>   Line: 834
>
> Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute
>   'ifconfig' is not allowed. Line: 891
>
> Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute
>   'ifconfig' is not allowed. Line: 903

I just copied the website from the main domain and set up on a subdomain and I found many errors. Please help.

Waiting for a quick response.

Comment: post your xml code that has error in `move` attribute

Comment: Could you please share your xml code?

Comment: any of your layout xml file contain ifconfig that is not allowed

Comment: can you please tell me path and name of xml file. I will share.